# R shiny one code to display graph, table and download data

Tags: r, shiny

In shiny, I want to use the same data set to produce and display a graph and a table, and to download the data in the table in csv format.

I start by loading a data table under server with code like

```
DTGlobal <- readRDS("bigfile")
```

I shiny selectInput() to set up some user input like the following

```
selectInput(inputId = "ScenarioName", label = "xxx", choices = scenarioNames)
```

Currently I create the same scenario-specific dataset in `renderTable()` and `renderPlot()` with

```
scenarioName <- input$availabilityScenarioName
DTlocal <- data.table::copy(DTGlobal[scenario %in% scenarioName)
add some further manipulations of DTlocal here
```

So far I have done graphs and tables by essentially duplicating code in `renderPlot()` and `renderTable()`. I can do the same thing with `downloadHandler()`. But I was wondering if there was some way to create the data at the server level which I could then access in functions below that. I think I could use `newDTGlobal <<- DTlocal` in `renderPlot()` (which is called first) but I think this would make it available to everyone. And if they ran the same `renderPlot()` that would wipe out my data.

Comment: did you look into `reactiveValues()`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figuring out how to use the reactive technology did the trick. Here's a code snippet of what I am now doing. It gets variable values from input and generates a data table using that information.

```
data.foodAvail <- reactive({
    countryName <- input$availabilityCountryName
    scenarioName <- input$availabilityScenarioName
    dt <- data.table::copy(dt.foodAvail.foodGroup)
    spiderData <- spiderGraphData(countryName, scenarioName, dt, displayColumnName = "food_group_code")
  })
```

The next bit of code shows how I use this (both chunks of code are in the server). The relevant bit of this is `data.foodAvail()`. This is the value generated above that is specific to the user-chosen input values.

The data.table copy is needed because `data.foodAvail()` is altered by a data table operation involving `:=` in the spiderGraphData function.

```
output$availabilitySpiderGraphP1 <- renderggiraph({
    dt <- data.table::dt <- data.table::copy(data.foodAvail()))
    scenarioName <- unique(dt$scenario)
    dt[, region_code.IMPACT159 := NULL]
    p <- spiderGraphOutput(dt, scenarioName)
    ggiraph(code = print(p), zoom_max = 1, width = .5)
  })
```